# Exporting/migrating data from an existing live site into our new development version

Tags: drupal

I need some help in exporting/migrating data from an existing live site into our new development version of the similar site.

Both the sites are in drupal7. The existing site has an 'event' node with custom fields added and it has some really unwanted fields in it. And it has more that 90 thousand records.
In our new website we have created a similar 'event' node but only with minimum fields and the machine names are also kind of changed to give meaningful words.

So now the problem is how do I get the data imported from my existing site into our new site. And the bigger problem is the machine names doesn't match so, how do I map the machine names between fields from both nodes.

And also I need to maintain the ids for realtionships as there are other entities related with this 'event' node. I want to try exporting say minimum records first say 50 or 100 as the existing data set is huge.

I am kind of new to drupal and doesnt know which module should I look into or Are there any good approach any of you can suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Machine names are unique in Drupal so it's tough to migrate the data's. Anyhow below link might help you to sync data between servers & database.

Comment: Thanks Shankar. I will look into these links